# What is the history behind the name of the xdev option in find?

Tags: find, history

I find the name of the xdev option counterintuitive. For me it seems like the abbreviation of 'cross device (search)'. However it does the opposite, it restricts the search to a single file system. The alternative but somewhat obsolete name is "mount", which is more memorizable. What is the history behind the naming of this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is even more complex that you might believe.

In the AT&T implementation for `find`, the feature is from `nftw()` which has been introduced with `SVr4` and `nftw()` did come with a flag `FTW_MOUNT` that stopped at mount points and did not report files with a different `st_dev` entry.

The `SVr4` `find` command did have both `-mount` and `-xdev` in 1988 and `-xdev` was an alias to `-mount`.

On the other side, `SunOS` and `BSD` had a `-xdev` in 1985 already and since the `SunOS`/ `BSD` `find`was not implemented on top of `*ftw()`, it could use a different sematic and it did. `find -xdev` on `SunOS` stopped descending after the mount point with the different `st_dev` has been printed.

Then in 1992, the first `POSIX` standard that included more than just `libc` and file formats (like tar) mentioned `find` with `-xdev` only. The problem with that POSIX standard  is that`-xdev` has to report mount points and to stop after reporting the moint points while the `AT&T`  implementation stopped before reporting mount points.

GNU find is an implementation that follows the POSIX.1-1992 text.

As a result, we recently discussed a related bug report on the POSIX standard teleconference and decided to enhance the standard with a `-mount` primary and with a `FTW_XDEV` flag in `nftw()`.

`find -mount` has to behave the way as `find` did behave on AT&T UNIX and must not report mount points.

`find -xdev` has to behave the way it was written in the POSIX standard and needs to report mount points and stop then with descending the tree.

This requires`AT&T` UNIX based `find` implementations to change their implementation for `-xdev` and to let GNU find change the behavior of `-mount`.

BTW: AFAIK, `sfind/libfind` is currently the only implementation that already follows the new rules.

Since `libfidnd` implemented the needed code already before the final agreement for POSIX has been set up, it implements a `-mount+` primary and `-xdev` now has become an alias to `-mount+` which is easier to memorize for stop at mount points but in addition report them.

Comment: GNU `find` existed before 1992. Note that at least on Linux, _devices_ (same filesystems, or subsets of same filesystems) can be mounted on several directory entries in the filesystem, so `-xdev` may cross mountpoints if it's a mountpoint of the same filesystem.

Comment: A GNU find changelog entry from 1990 has: *For -xdev, process filesystem
        mountpoints (but don't descend them), instead of skipping them
        entirely.*, so it was an  intentional change back then.

Comment: So why do you believe that GNU find implemented it wrong, in special as the implemented behavior is in conflict with the documented behavior for `nftw()`?

Comment: On the same 1990 date, another changelog entry mentions POSIX for xargs, so it seems possible indeed that GNU find used to behave like SVR4 but changed to match text in some POSIX draft.

Comment: BTW, do you know when `du -x` was added? It seems it wasn't there in svr4

Comment: `du -x` has been added with `XPG4` around 1994.It was not in the original SVr4.

Comment: Actually, [`-xdev` comes from BSD](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/b765761db3d96f182851b82fcd9688b2fef0f6bc) (1985; no `-mount` there) not SysV and behaves like modern versions of GNU `find`, so by your definition of _broken_ (doesn't behave like the original implementation), it's the svr4 one that is broken.

Comment: `nftw()` includes  the behavior from SVr4 `-mount`, but not what POSIX defined for `-xdev`. It is pretty useless to ask for a behavior that is not supported by the basic tree walk feture from libc. On the other side, SunOS-3.5 implements -xdev with the POSIX definition and does not use `*ftw()`. Given than the same putback in BSD added `-ls` and `-ls` is from SunOS, it seems that the related code was imported from SunOS. So it may be that the people who wrote the POSIX text did not know about the differences in the behavior.

Comment: SunOS 2.0 had neither `-ls` nor `-xdev`. 3.5 was rebased on BSD4.3, it seems unlikely `-xdev` came from SunOS. What makes you say `-ls` comes from SunOS?

Comment: SunOS was never based on BSD-4.3. SunOS-3.5 was based on previous SunOS-3.x versions and SunOS-3.0 was based on BSD-4.2 and BSD-4.2 did not have `-xdev`. The problem may be (that up to AFAIK 1986) there was a close relation between BSD and Sun, since Bill Joy still was the head of OS development at UCB.

Comment: Sorry, I misread https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SunOS about BSD4.3 rebasing. I did verify that SunOS 2.0 (released in May 1985) didn't have `-xdev`/`-ls` though.

Comment: But SunOS-3.0 was published in December 2005 already (this is when I received my first Sun-3 machine with SunOS-3.0) and has been developed in the time before. So I guess this was some kind of joined development. What you call SunOS-2.0 (but never had that name) is from Spring 1985 and the next release came out with the Sun-3 hardware. The first regular Sun-3 machines have been build December 24 1985 and arrived in Berlin at December 27 together with SunOS-3.0 install tape.

Comment: You forgot to amend your _The feature is from nftw() from SVr4_ after adding the SunOS/BSD stuff. As the rest of your answer clarifies, the feature is not from svr4

Comment: BSDs couldn't have used `ftw` because ftw came from SysV, v7 didn't have it, and anyway it didn't have FTW_MOUNT. BSDs added their own tree walking library (fts) much later. A FTS_XDEV was added in 1990 and `find` started using `fts` after that there.

Answer (score 2):

It most probably stands for cross-device indeed, though in effect it means *do **not** cross devices*.

In the [original implementation on BSD in 1985](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/fc5086f226a655430312b864e898fc0bb340444d), the code had:

```
int    Xdev = 1;       /* true if SHOULD cross devices (file systems) */
[...]
   else if (EQ(a, "-xdev")) {
           Xdev = 0;
```

Where `Xdev` was an internal variable used to track whether devices should be crossed. The `-xdev` predicate sets that to 0.

David Korn at AT&T added a similar predicate a few years later for SVR4 with a `-mount` alias for it (that mirrors the `FTW_MOUNT` flag of the new tree walking library).

I don't find the `-mount` option particularly better. Assuming it stands for *single-mount*, it's also misleading on Linux at least where you can have several mount points for a file system.

```
$ mkdir -p a/b b
$ sudo mount --bind a b
```

Now `b` is a mountpoint on the same *device* as `.` and `a`.

```
$ find . -xdev
.
./b
./b/b
./a
./a/b
$ find . -mount
.
./b
./b/b
./a
./a/b
```

`find` doesn't cross-devices when processing `b`, but it's a different *mount* point so `-mount` (as single-mount) is more misleading that `-xdev` (as long as you remember it's about **preventing** crossing devices).

Comment: Unless you can present us the SCCS history for `find` on `SunOS`, you cannot verify whether `SunOS` or `BSD` introduced the `-xdev` feature.

Comment: @schily, the commit I link is dated 1985-06-07, shortly after SunOS 2.0 was released (wikipedia mentions May 1985). SunOS 2.0 didn't have `-xdev`, SunOS 3.0 was not shipped before September 1985. I couldn't verify whether 3.0 had `-xdev`. 3.2 definitely had (with a SCCS id for `find.c` of `find.c 1.1 86/07/08 SMI`). As you say, there was probably a lot of collaboration between Sun and Berkeley.In any case, it's not unfair to call those early SunOS systems BSDs, like macOS is now often classified as a BSD system.

Comment: Never trust in SCCS `SID`s in sources taken from univertity source trees. Sun did call a recursive `get -k` followed by a creation of a dummy SCCS tree based on these files. As a result, the `SID`s always were `1.1` with the date of the creation of the related university source tree. Given that there have been more people working at Sun, the probability that this did come from Sun is high in special since the user `serge` was only active for a few months in 1985 and mostly caused putbacks that definitly did come from other sources.